# Basic object creation in Objective-C from a Java perspective

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop

I have a very basic OOP question regarding Objective-C.  I come from a Java background, and I know when creating objects from a class, I use constructors.  I realize that this is not the case in Objective-C.  I've created the following class to work with my arrays, that also contain my utility methods for it:

```
@interface ObjectList : NSObject {

NSMutableArray *oList;
NSArray *sortedObjects;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *oList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sortedObjects;

- (NSMutableArray *) removeDuplicates:(NSMutableArray *)uList;
- (NSArray *) sortAlpha:(NSMutableArray *)sortedArray :(NSMutableArray *)objList;
- (NSMutableArray *) compileCategories:(NSMutableArray *)cArray;



@end
```

My question to you is, how do I instantiate an object of type ObjectList, that will allow me to use the rList, and sortedObjects variables in the object, and use them with the methods that I have created above?  Personally, the only way I know how to create an object in Objective-C is:

```
MyClass *objectName = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

What would my syntax be in the case, using the kind of class that I have created above?

Comment: Thanks very much too all of those who replied.  I really appreciate the help, and the feedback!  Take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do you have the following choices.

One:

You may create an init method like so "Think of an init as an constructor in java":

```
(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        oList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        sortedObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Two:

If you want to pass arguments to your "consturctor" or in other words to initialize an object with some values when you create it do the following:

```
- (id)initWithOList:(NSMutableArray*)objectList andSortedObjects:(NSArray*)sObjects {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        oList = [objectList copy];
        sortedObjects = [sObjects copy]
    }
    return self;
}
```

and don't forget to release oList and sortedObjects. In both of the above cases.

```
-(void)dealloc{
   [oList release];
   [sortedObjects release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

So in objective-C you have to think of a constructor as an init method. You should read about memory management as it gets confusing at the beginning.

Comment: More complete than my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Cyprian, and Daniel T. for your prompt replies.  I learned a very important concept from the two of you with this one question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You answered your own question:

```
ObjectList* objectList = [[ObjectList alloc] init];
```

However, you probably also want to write an `init` method that actually creates objects and places them in the member variables:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        oList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        sortedObjects = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and of course you want to get rid of them when you are done:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [oList release];
    [sortedObjects release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you declare properties on an object, you need accessor methods. Either write them yourself, or let the compiler do the work, using `@synthesize`, which will create standard setters/getters. That said, `alloc init` will work just fine.

As a matter of fact, the `init` method is the standard constructor function. For Java programmers like you ;) there's also the alternative `new` syntax

```
 [ObjectList new]
```

which does exactly the same thing as `alloc init`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take the time to read through [this Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163). If you're already familiar with Java, it won't take much time, and then you won't have to ask many questions here in SO.

That said, let me add a few points:

1. In Objective-C, allocation and initialization are split into `alloc` and `init...`.
2. You send the `alloc` message to the class object `MyClass`, to allocate an uninitialized chunk of memory, `[MyClass alloc]` .
3. Then you send the `init...` message to that object, creating an initialized object. Thus you combine the two and write

   ```
   [[MyClass alloc] init...]
   ```
4. It's your own responsibility to write `init...` method. It's typically has the form

   ```
   -(id)init
   {
        if(self=[super init]){
             ... do your own initializations ...
        }
        return self;
   }
   ```
5. It's very important to have the line `self=[super init]`, because the super can decide to use as `self` different chunks of memory if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be asking how to apply the code to all arrays you work with in your project? If so, you may want to use [Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-SW1)

> A category allows you to add methods
>   to an existing class—even to one for
>   which you do not have the source.
>   Categories are a powerful feature that
>   allows you to extend the functionality
>   of existing classes without
>   subclassing. Using categories, you can
>   also distribute the implementation of
>   your own classes among several files.